# Cournot nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, self-study, nash-equilibrium

The market demand for a good is described by the inverse demand function $P(Q) = 120 - Q $ where $Q$ is total quantity demanded and $P(Q)$ the market price. Two firms $i =1,2$ have identical cost functions $c_i(q_i) =0.5 q_i^2$ where $q_i$ denotes firm i's output quantity hence $Q=q_1+q_2$.

a) Find the Cournot Nash Equilibrium.

b) Suppose that both firms cooperate by making the arrangement to produce joint profit maximizing quantity $Q^M$ together (i.e. every firm has to produce $Q^M/2$). Compute that quantity. What is firm 1's best response if firm 2 indeed produces $Q^M/2$ ? does this arrangement constitute a Nash equilibrium?

---

My Answer:

Part(a) is straightforward. So I found that $q_1^*=q_2^*=30$

Part(b)

For firm i $\forall i =1,2$

$$\pi_i (q_1,q_2)=(120-Q^M)(Q^M/2)-0.5 (Q^M)^2/4$$

$$\partial \pi_i/ \partial Q^M = 120-Q^M-(1/4)Q^M=0$$

$$120 = 5/4 Q^M $$

$$Q^M = 96$$

so $$q_1 = q_2 = 96/2 = 48$$

since $48 \not= 30$, this result is not Nash equilibrium.

Does this answer make sense? I am not sure about that. Please share your ideas and corrections with me. Thank you.

Comment: You have an error: check where the 120 comes from when you take the derivative. As a rule, competitive quantities should be above collusive quantities.

Comment: Er, check where the 120 comes from *in $\partial \pi_i / \partial Q^M$*